# Visual Studio (.exe) export not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, export, sdl-2

I've made a simple program in c++ and SDL that utilizes both SDL_Mixer and SDL_Image. However when I try to run the `.exe` in the debug folder I receive a black screen with no sound or images despite the program working quite properly in Visual Studio. All the dll's are where they should be and I've made sure everything should work. So why am I receiving a black screen instead of my program. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I receive ... no ... images **despite the program working quite properly in Visual Studio**.

If you're using relative paths to load external resources like images then verify your program's [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) matches what it is when Visual Studio launches it.